# Right align content in ListBox

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'd like to right align some content in `ListBox` `ItemTemplate`in a way that its position doesn't change based on the width of the remaining `ItemTemplate` elements.

Here's a screenshot of what I'd like to achieve:

[image: Right aligned icon]

Here's the XAML I'm trying to use:

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Grid Margin="12 12 0 0" 
                  Width="60" Height="60" 
                  VerticalAlignment="Top"
                  Background="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}">
                <Image Source="/Assets/Mystery.png" />
            </Grid>
            <StackPanel x:Name="ParentStackPanel">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextLargeStyle}" x:Name="NameText" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Owner, StringFormat='by {0}'}"
                           Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSmallStyle}" />
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="FixedWidthGrid" >
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Width="18"
                                   Text="{Binding ContainerSize, Converter={StaticResource ContainerSizeConverter}}"
                                   Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" />
                        <TextBlock Margin="0" Text="{Binding Difficulty, StringFormat='{}{0:N1}'}"
                                   Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" />
                        <TextBlock Margin="0" Text="/"
                                   Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" />
                        <TextBlock Margin="0" Text="{Binding Terrain, StringFormat='{}{0:N1}'}"
                                   Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                        <Image Source="/Assets/Favorite.png" Height="24" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

In the snippet I've named the element I'm having problems with as `FixedWidthGrid`. With the above XAML the icon is right aligned inside the `ParentStackPanel`, the width of which depends on the `NameText`, i.e. the widthest element inside it. In the image above the icon would be aligned with the end of the word `Ukova`. If the text is too wide to fit, the icon might even be pushed out of the screen.

I can solve that by setting fixed width to `FixedWidthGrid` but since I want my page to work both in portrait and landscape mode, I can't do that. And I haven't even tested it with different resolutions, supported on WP8.

Is there a way to bind the width of `FixedWidthGrid` relative to page width so that it would change every time the page width changes (because of orientation switch)? Or is there another way to get the icon aligned as I want it to?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11016806/c-sharp-windows-phone-alignment-in-xaml-listbox-itemtemplate/11018672#11018672) describes the main problem with using a ListBox to display data all the way to the right. For your example, I would not use a StackPanel on the outside and instead use a Grid that had three columns defined that make the middle column take up as much space as it can

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

In the first column place your 60x60 image. In the second column place your text. This can be a StackPanel. And in the third Column place your small image. This alignment, combined with changing the HorizontalAlignment of the ListBoxItem will render what you desire.

Comment: Thanks! I had to adapt your solution a bit to my case but the key changes were switching from `StackPanel`to `Grid` on the outside and setting `HorizontalAlignment` of `ListBoxItem` to `Stretch`.