# Xaml, middle column not taking up full width

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, windows-phone-8, alignment

How do I make my middle column take up the full width available while allowing space for the comment section so that all those comment boxes are nicely aligned to the right:

[image]

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ActivityStreamItemTemplate">
        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="5,0,0,0">
            <Button Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.LoadSpacesCommand, ElementName=OrganisationList}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" Padding="-5,0,-5,-5" Margin="-7,-12,-7,-7" Height="auto" BorderThickness="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" UseLayoutRounding="True" FontSize="0.01">
                <Grid Height="auto">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="67" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="60" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <StackPanel Height="auto" Grid.Column="0" Background="Transparent">
                        <Border Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" Width="62" Height="62" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,5">
                            <Image Source="{Binding created_by.image.link}" Width="62" Height="62"></Image>
                        </Border>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Height="auto" Grid.Column="1">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding type}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="30" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,5" Foreground="White" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ttitle}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="15" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,5" Foreground="White" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding created_by.name}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="11" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,5" Foreground="White" />
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Height="60" Grid.Column="2" Margin="10,0,0,0">
                        <StackPanel.Background>
                            <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="/Assets/Icons/CommentsIcon.png"/>
                        </StackPanel.Background>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding comments.Count}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="20" Foreground="Black" TextAlignment="Center" Padding="0,8,0,0"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

I tried placing horizontal align on the third stackpanel but that actually didn't work.

EDIT: Thanks for the tries but no cigar:

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Right align content in ListBox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14539961/right-align-content-in-listbox)

Comment: This is a common question and quite frustrating that you have to work around something that should be default. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14539961/right-align-content-in-listbox/14543768#14543768

Comment: James, did you look at the link in my comment? This is your solution

Comment: I sure did Shawn. auto, *, auto does not work unfortunately.. Perhaps I missed the point? any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, but I think you did miss the point. You should not use a stack panel as the parent item. see my answer(s)

Comment: Thanks mate, going to check this out now I understand, hah!

Answer (score 2):

You need to alter the style of the `ListBoxItem` itself to ensure that the content is stretched across the available width.

Define this style:

```
<Style x:Key="ListBoxItemStyle" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
</Style>
```

Then the Right alignment of the "Comments" image will work and the central text box will stretch to fill the available space.

You might find that just using a `StackPanel` with an horizontal orientation works better than a `Grid` for the item template, especially if the data in columns 0 and 2 are a constant width.

Comment: Thanks Chris, i'll give that a go when I get home. Next on the List (excuse the pun) is never ending lists - virtualizing (apparently what it's called) :) thanks for all your hard work!

Answer (score 0):

Play around with the space given for the columns, for example:

```
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="67" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

This gives the center column 3 times more space than the right column

Comment: How does this change with no resolutions coming into play? All relative I assume because of the *?

Comment: Yes, the first 67 is in WPF 'pixels' (ideally 1/96 of an inch).  The other two are relative widths which will change based on the space available

Comment: Thanks for the try, I have explicitly used your attempt and also tries to set the last width to 60 (as my message box really just should be 60)... unfortunately it didn't really work.. although it certainly did push them over a little more.. if anything, it's better. so thanks for the try! so OP for new visuals

Comment: You might change the vertical alignment (and content alignment) on the containing button to stretch.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell exactly what you want because of how you've blurred your image. But I think the key is to make the container of the grid take up all available space, `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"`.

```
<DataTemplate>
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="67" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="60" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <!-- items here -->
        </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```

The item you set to have `Grid.Column="0"` will have width 67dip, the one with `Grid.Column="2"` will be width 60dip, and the one with `Grid.Column="1"`will fill up the rest of the space.

dip = device independent pixels - all Windows Phone apps are measured as if the screen is 480x800 and then rendered at the actual resolution of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Inside a StackPanel you can't do HorizontalAlignment to right while its orientation is LeftToRight, as far as I know. Avoid using it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem stems from using a StackPanel as the top-most UIElement. Use a Grid instead and follow the rest of this advice:
[Right align content in ListBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14539961/right-align-content-in-listbox/14543768#14543768)

Which leads to this answer as well:
[C# windows phone -Alignment in xaml ListBox.ItemTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11016806/c-sharp-windows-phone-alignment-in-xaml-listbox-itemtemplate/11018672#11018672)

Comment: Ahhh, i'll give it a try wen I get back matey, thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the Button, if it's not mandatory try deleting it and add a "Tap" Event to the StackPanel, i've tried it and it works.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ActivityStreamItemTemplate">

    <StackPanel Tap="...">
        // no <Button> here
            <Grid>
                ---
            </Grid>
        // no </Button> here
    </StackPanel>

</DataTemplate>
```

better option

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ActivityStreamItemTemplate">

    <Grid Tap="...">
        ...
    </Grid>

</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Can you still bind Command to this? (I would try but I currently am at work and do not have vs here) Tap=Bind MyCommand